# How to load a gridview using volley request and glide/picasso?

Tags: android, gridview, android-volley, picasso, android-glide

I am new to Android, I am trying to populate a gridview from images in the form of bitmaps from a webservice. (I have no control over the webservices). I was able to load the gridview using async task but when I click or cancel the activity/fragment, the async doenst cancel/stop and hence the next activity doesnt open until all the async task is completed.

I had asked a question about this earlier and one of the developer here advice I use Picasso/glide. I am not sure how i use volley to fetch the bitmap and set that to the picasso/glide. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I can't comment yet. I just want to complete Kelevandos answer by saying that you need to add:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

in your build.gradle (app), or Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.picasso</groupId>
    <artifactId>picasso</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

to import Picasso. [Here](http://square.github.io/picasso/) is the link to Picasso's main page explaining with more details different function available.

Comment: I dont have an URL for each image, since I am calling a webservice and by sending in the details of the image through xml.

Comment: You can make the call of Picasso `.load()` with an URL, a drawable, a File, or a String of a file path. If you have a bitmap, you can create a file and use that file to load it

Comment: Picasso is designed to efficiently use cache. If the bitmap is in memory, it will load from there. In any case, Picasso is incredibly fast.

Comment: Thank you TheSunshinator but seems like its getting hard to scroll bcos of further conversion of the bitmap into file. Also I want the activity to terminate when i click on the picture leading to next activity and that doenst happen untill all the images to grid are fetched.:(

Answer (score 3):

You so not use Volley with Picasso nor Glide :-) In the place where you put data into the item View of the GridView you simply call the method from the library to load the image from an url :)

With Picasso it will look like this:

```
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .into(imageView);
```

And with Glide like this:

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(url)
    .into(imageView);
```

Simple as that, the library will do the rest for you :-) Also, use only one of them, not both ^^ I would suggest Picasso, it is easier to start with from my experience.

Comment: The only reason I am wanting to use both is that, I am downloading images from a webservice to which i send an xml with image information. I donoo how i could do that with picasso.